# Is there a way to prevent user from changing JS script location?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am creating a JS API that is made to fetch data from my website. To use the API, user is required to include the script  in their website html. The API will then display data from my website into their website accordingly. I am using ajax to call the endpoint url of my website.

However, insecurity concern is that, malicious user can create their own API and call the endpoint url.

I was thinking of checking server HTTP_REFERER, getting script id then checking the src of the script. However, the server HTTP_REFERER can be changed programmatically.

Is there a way to prevent user from changing JS script location or checking if the script src has been changed? Or in general, how can I prevent user from using their own script or cURL to call my endpoint url?

I am using PHP LARAVEL as backend language.

Comment: The API needs to be callable by the visitors of the site that included the script. That makes it so that any prevention methods needs to be circumventable by your script which in turn makes it public knowledge since your script is public. You might make it a bit harder (especially from a browser if you can enable CORS for specific domains beforehand) but anyone with cURL will be able to replicate whatever your scripts does.

Comment: No way to stop using your API programmatically

Comment: Can you generate a md5 or sha256 hash for proof of js file.

Comment: @TirdadAbbasi That is the point? The caller would be responsible for adhering to it or passing it back. The caller can choose to ignore it or pass back a fictitious value.

Comment: There's no way to protect your API. Any request the browser makes (which is logged by the browser for the user to see), can be replicated using cURL or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no certain way to prevent this on the client side. It's always right to secure the backend. To authorize users, try using OAuth 2.0; Laravel passport is a good implementation. This will secure your APIs.